# An error occured when injecting AuthzClient

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Injecting AuthzClient in quarkus 1.13 an error occured.

```
@Inject
AuthzClient authzClient;
```

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices#authzClient
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1081)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:255)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:129)
        at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:419)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices#authzClient
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.github.jithset.services.KeycloakServices]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:484)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:378)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:247)
```

If that is not possible how can i check if user has certain permission with access token.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on Quarkus security, but I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to use the Keycloak `AuthzClient` manually. Instead, use one of the Quarkus security extensions: https://quarkus.io/guides/#security

Comment: Any update? I've the same problem in Quarkus 2.5.4.Final and can't inject the AuthzClient.

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with @loicmathieu and @Ladicek. If you want to manage protected resources you NEED to be able to inject the AuthzClient.

This a common usecase when you want to implement user managed authorization. A good example is in the keycloak quickstart repo : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-uma-photoz.

There is an IT test where the AuthzClient is injected in the official quarkus repository : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/9b09229b86b775a9452d09fca42f18e32f81e924/integration-tests/keycloak-authorization/src/main/java/io/quarkus/it/keycloak/ProtectedResource.java

And the use of the AuthzClient is documented here : https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization#injecting-the-authorization-client

After some experimentation I found that the AuthzClient bean will only exist when `quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true` is added to the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check for permissions is to use the security annotations as explained in the [USING OAUTH2 RBAC](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oauth2) guide or injext the security context via `@Context SecurityContext ctx`.

If you want to have access to the token, assuming you're using the authorization code flow, you can inject the JWT token via `@Inject JwtToken jwtToken`, more details in the [USING OPENID CONNECT TO PROTECT WEB APPLICATIONS USING AUTHORIZATION CODE FLOW](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication) guide.

If you"re using Keycloack, you can also inject a `io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity` but as @Ladicek said you're not supposed to directly used internal Keycloack classes, see the [USING OPENID CONNECT AND KEYCLOAK TO CENTRALIZE AUTHORIZATION](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization) guide.